# Changing the color of the container border color

Tags: flutter, dart

I have four containers and would like to make a quiz app. I need to  change the container border color when selected. For example, when I select the right option only, the selected option color needs to change to green. When I select the wrong option, the wrong option needs to show as red, and at the same time the right answer also needs to show as green. I am struggling with how to make the code for changing the color. Help me the right way to do this. All I would like is changing the color of the container border when I tap.

```
SizedBox(height: 20),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              ), //boxdecoration
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ), //decoration
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Answer 1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16), //textStyle
                        ), //text
                        Container(
                          height: 26,
                          width: 26,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                          ), //boxdecoration
                        ), //container
                      ], //widget
                    ), //row
                  ), //container
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the selected index will be null. also, we know the right answer index.
In order to archive that, we can include two variables inside state class.

```
 int _rightAnswerIndex = 2;
 int? tappedIndex;
```

On every answer pressed, we will assign the `tappedIndex`

```
                    setState(() {
                      tappedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },`
```

To control the color of the border, first we will check if the index is tapped or not,

- if not tapped, just pass default color or null color, or just `Colors.transparent`
- if tapped check the option is right answer or not then assign color

like

```dart
             color: tappedIndex != null
                            ? _rightAnswerIndex == index 
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.red
                            : Colors.transparent,
                      ),,
```

**Full State class with Container**

```dart
class _AnimTestState extends State<AnimTest> {
  int _rightAnswerIndex = 2;
  int? tappedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ...List.generate(
              4,
              (index) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      tappedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: tappedIndex != null
                            ? _rightAnswerIndex == index 
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.red
                            : Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text("Answer $index"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```